# bash script to check if a file exists over a certain size

Tags: bash

I'm trying to automate an archive process and I'm unsure how to go about a particular aspect.

Currently I manually check whether any files exist over a certain size with
find . -size +4194304k -print and if it comes back without any files I'll use cpio if does I'll use tar. How would I test fot that condition?

Thanks

Bryan

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

# For a list of files
#large_files=`find . -size +4194304k -print`

# For a test of files
large_files=`find . -size +4194304k -print | cut -c1`

if [[ -z $large_files ]]
then
    # No large files
else
    # Large files present
fi
```

Just to clarify about return codes and exit codes:

```
# Exit codes

$ find . -name foo && s=$?
$ echo $s
0

$ find . -name f1 && s=$?
./f1
$ echo $s
0

# Return codes

$ s=$(find . -name foo)
$ [[ ! $s ]] && echo "N"
N

$ s=$(find . -name f1)
$ [[ $s ]] && echo "Y"
Y
```

Comment: You could even add a `| head` to the `find` command in order to prevent `$large_files` to occupy too much space.

Comment: @glglgl Thanks for the suggestion. I've added cut -c1 to the command

Comment: That's bogus. `find` will only return true if some files were found. So `if find ... >/dev/null; then tar ... ; else cpio ... ; fi`

Comment: @tripleee if large_files is zero length (i.e. find returned zero files) then there are no large files.. what's bogus about that??

Comment: Unix utilities have an exit code for precisely this reason. Parsing their output is often brittle and at the very least rarely the most elegant or idiomatic solution. In short, it's an antipattern.

Comment: @tripleee The exit code is zero regardless so long as there isn't an error. You are catching the return value, not the exit code

Comment: @tripleee BTW large_files was present in case the list was required later in the script

Comment: Hi All Thanks for the hand with that, much appreciated

Comment: @Cez; no, `find` will return nonzero if no files were found. This is quite by design.